# Python: Splitting a string at any uppercase letter (as part of a rename for a column name)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I would like to rename columns in a Pandas dataframe using *rename* function and therefore I would like to split the name (string) at an uppercase letter within the string.
So for example my column names are something like 'FooBar' or 'SpamEggs' and one column is called 'Monty-Python'. My goal are column names like 'foo_bar' 'spam_eggs' and 'monty_python'.

I know that

```
'-'.join(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'FooBar'))
```

will give me 
    `Foo-Bar`

But this cannot be included in my *rename* function:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().lower().replace("-", "_"), inplace=True)
```

(should go between *strip* and *lower* but gives back a Syntax Error).

Can anyone help me to include the snippet to *rename* or help me find another solution than *findall*?

Comment: You might find it easier to create a function `def rename(name)` that contains the renaming functionality instead of trying to cram it all into a lambda. Then you could do `df.rename(columns=rename, inplace=True)`. This would make the transformations simpler and make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove anything that is not a letter
2. Prepend an underscore (`_`) to uppercase letters that are not at the start of the string
3. Lowercase the result

```
df.columns
Index(['FooBar', 'SpamEggs', 'Monty-Python'], dtype='object')

df.columns.str.replace('[\W]', '')\
          .str.replace('(?<!^)([A-Z])', r'_\1')\
          .str.lower()
Index(['foo_bar', 'spam_eggs', 'monty_python'], dtype='object')
```

This solution generalises quite nicely. Assign the result back to `df.columns`.

Comment: Oh mighty king of regex, it worked like a charm! Thank you!